# How to deal with many-to-many in django / tastypie

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have the following two models, that should have many-to-many between them:

```
class Blueprint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name", ]


class Workload(models.Model):
    blueprints = models.ManyToManyField('Blueprint', db_constraint=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    flavor = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name", ]
```

Being totally new to django and tastypie, I have a couple of questions:

1) What is the proper syntax to specify many-to-many between the Blueprint and Workload, so when a new Blueprint record is created, it does not run into a database constrains, complaining that the related Workload record can not be empty

2)  What is the proper syntax for my api.py, to have the related Workload link as a part of GET /api/blueprint/1 output, as well as to have a Blueprint link  as a part of GET /api/workload/1 output

I would imagine, that having many-to-many is very common to django / tastypie apps, and it has been solved long ago, but, I was unable to find a clean solution to this (and I'new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what issues you are having, but you should add primary keys to each model, typically an auto int field.

```
class Blueprint(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name", ]


class Workload(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blueprints = models.ManyToManyField('Blueprint', db_constraint=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    flavor = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name", ]
```

You should be able to create a blueprint without a workload.  However, with current syntax you Can Not have a workload without a blueprint assigned.  If you want to allow workloads with no blueprint, then add `null=True, blank=True` to that field.

as for the url; there is tons of posts on here that show how to setup a url like your asking.

Comment: With the additions you have suggested, I am able to create new Blueprint records:  b1 = Blueprint(name="b 1", description="b 1 desc")   , and then add Workloads to them:   b1.workloads.create(name="w 1", description="w 1 desc", blueprint=b1) .   However, when I do GET /api/blueprint/1/  -  I get this:   {"description": "b 1 desc", "id": 1, "name": "b 1", "resource_uri": "/api/blueprint/1/", "workloads": []}  - As you can see, the "workloads: link does not show any child workloads

Comment: I created a gist with the resource detail:   https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/25b98d9dabc13ba0221a

Comment: and here is the gist with the models detail:    https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/f3159284f513f5a88282

Comment: Sorry, i haven't worked in tastypi; but form some searching on here, I think it may need the .ToManyField; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767740/django-tastypie-posting-to-a-resource-having-manytomany-field-with-through-rela

Comment: Thank you, this is useful stuff!